# java card ECC encryption cipher support

Tags: public-key-encryption, javacard

I am new to java card development.i want to build java card applet which encrypt data using ECC cryptography.So i am using jcop41 card and it support ECC .so i want to know what are the cipher class support ECC.I want same encryption like in here(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669625/java-card-rsa-encryption) using ECC. But in here they used  `Cipher.ALG_RSA_PKCS1` .But ECC we can't use this cipher.can you give me any sugession??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge encryption based on ECC is not available in the Java Card API, only [Signature](http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/apis/jc222/javacard/security/Signature.html) (i.e. ECDSA)and [KeyAgreement](http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/apis/jc222/javacard/security/KeyAgreement.html) (i.e. ECDH). Just look for constants with names that start with "`ALG_EC_`" in those classes. There might be NXP specific extensions to the API though.

Here's a [paper describing how to implement ECIE in Java Card](http://digital.csic.es/bitstream/10261/42886/1/CISIS11-GT-1893%20v1.0.pdf) (wich I found by Googling: ["java card" elliptic curve encryption](http://google.com/?q=elliptic+curve+encryption+%22java+card%22)...).